# Mongoose full text search wrong return

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm currently working on a nodejs project with mongoose and tried to use the mongoose feature full text search. So first I created the index of my model :

```
schema.index({author: 'text', email: 'text'});
```

And next created the function Search :

```
Database.prototype.Search = function(search,callback){
Model
.find(
    { $text : { $search : search } }, 
    { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
.exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.stack || err);
        throw err;
    } else {
        callback(data);
    }
});
};
```

And for finish, I created some data.

- id: 1 / author: test / test85264@gmail.com
- id: 2 / author: test2 / test85264@gmail.com
- id: 3 / author: test3 / test85264@gmail.com

And the result are really curious, for example when I'm searching "test" it returns me only one result (id: 1) whereas it should return me all the data (id: 1, 2, 3) because it's a full text search.

Same with the email, when I'm searching "test85264" it returns me all the data but if I searching "test8526" it returns me nothing.

Something wrong or missing in my code ? Thanks per advance !

PokeRwOw

Comment: "The $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match."

Comment: @BrianShamblen Ah ok ! So it's not a full text search... Is there any tool in mongoose which makes finding blueberry if we search on the term blue ?

Comment: You could perform a regex search on the desired fields, but it could be very slow against a large collection.